# How long should Apache IoTDB took to not report "may not ready now" after startup?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am a newbie to Apache IoTDB and I am trying to install IoTDB, but during the startup process it kept warning "may not ready now, please wait and retry later". How to deal with this error? It has been reporting this error for more than half an hour. Is this warning for this long normal?

I checked the official website and haven't found any specific information about this error. I hope to solve my problem for this error itself.